# The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection error cascade dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i try to cascade dropdownlist in MVC4.
i have 2 dropdown list 1 - Category
2 - SubCategory.

When the user create new product he need to choose Category and then a SubCategory that related to the category. 
i use ajax with jason .

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<Category> allcategories = new List<Category>();
        List<SubCategory> allSubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();

        using (WebStoreEntities1 db1 = new WebStoreEntities1())
        {
            allcategories = db1.Categories.OrderBy(x => x.CategoryName).ToList();
        }

        ViewBag.categoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
        ViewBag.SubCategoryID = new SelectList(allSubCategories, "SubCategoryId",    "SubCategoryName");

        return View(main);
    }
```

in the html page the Jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var $SubCategoryID = $('#SubCategoryID');

        $('#CategoryID').change(function () {

            var CategoryID = $('#categoryID').val();

            if (!isNaN(CategoryID)) {
                var ddCategory = $("#SubCategoryID");
                ddCategory.empty();
                ddCategory.append($("<option></option>").val("").html("Sub Category!"));
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetSubCategories", "StoreManager")',
                    data: { CategoryID: CategoryID },
                    //dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('success',data)//for test 
                        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                            ddCategory.append(
                            //$SubCategoryID.append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(val.SubCategoryId).html(val.SubCategoryName)
                                );
                        });
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

and the code handels this request is:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSubCategories(string categoryID )
    {
        List<CategoryToSubCategory> allSubCategory = new List<CategoryToSubCategory>();
        int id = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(categoryID,out id))
        {
            using(WebStoreEntities1 db1 = new WebStoreEntities1())
            {
                allSubCategory = db1.CategoryToSubCategories.Where(a => a.CategoryId.Equals(id)).OrderBy(a => a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName).ToList();
            }
        }
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data=allSubCategory,
                JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data="error"
            };
        }

    }
```

The CategoryToSubCategory Model:

```
public partial class CategoryToSubCategory
{
    public int CategoryToSubId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }
}
```

all work but in the html insted to get the category name i get an erorr and in the console i see this error: 500 server error:
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

What I need to do ?

Comment: Can you show `CategoryToSubCategory`? It looks like you have navigation properties that are being lazy loaded when serializing the JSON. If so try with `db1.CategoryToSubCategories.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Select(a => new {a.SubCategory.SubCategoryId, a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName}).ToList()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When serializing the json response the code will try to lazy load and serialize `Product and`SubCategory`. You can fix it by projecting the result of your query into an anonymous type that just contains SubCategoryId and SubCategoryName, using a Select statement.

The idea would be applied in your `GetSubCategories` method as:

```
using(WebStoreEntities1 db1 = new WebStoreEntities1())
{
    allSubCategory = db1.CategoryToSubCategories
                        .Where(a => a.CategoryId.Equals(id))
                        .OrderBy(a => a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName)
                        .Select(a => new {
                                      SubCategoryId = a.SubCategoryId, 
                                      SubCategoryName = a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName })
                        .ToList();
}
```

So now you can no longer declare the `allSubCategory` variable at the beggining of the method as its type is an anonymous type.
You can however change your method as:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSubCategories(string categoryID )
{        
    int id = 0;
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() && int.TryParse(categoryID,out id))
    {
        using(WebStoreEntities1 db1 = new WebStoreEntities1())
        {
            var allSubCategory = db1.CategoryToSubCategories
                                    .Where(a => a.CategoryId.Equals(id))
                                    .OrderBy(a => a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName)
                                    .Select(a => new {
                                          SubCategoryId = a.SubCategoryId, 
                                          SubCategoryName = a.SubCategory.SubCategoryName })
                                    .ToList();

            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data=allSubCategory,
                JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };                
        }
    }
    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data="error",
        JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };        
}
```

Comment: its show me an error:Error1Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VirtualWebStore.Models.CategoryToSubCategory>

Comment: That is because `allSubCategory` no longer would be a `List<CategoryToSubCategory>` so you will need to take that into account in your method. I have updated the answer to clarify that

Comment: now i got this error: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: My bad, I meant to keep the same Linq statements using the anonymous method. Just edited the answer